# can not display shortcode content

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

i used the following shortcode to display play and download button in my website. BUt the shortcode works fine when the content is expanded but it appear as a code when the content is minimized, not sure how to fix it, please help. you can go to the [**website**](http://lightsandmusic.transwebsolutions.com/) and see problem there.

```
add_shortcode('myplaylist','playlist_function');
function playlist_function($atts)
{
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'title'=>'',
        'url'=>'#',
        ),$atts));

$output='<div class="songlinks" style="margin:5px 5px; width:30px; height:30px; float:left;">
<a href="'.$url.'" title="'.$title.'" name="'.$title.'" class="playbutton">  </a>
</div>
<div class="songdownloadlinks" style="margin:5px 5px; width:40px; float:left; height:30px;">
<a href="#" target="_blank" title="Download-'.$title.'" track_raw_url="'.$url.'">  </a>
</div>
<div style="padding:10px 5px;">'.$title.'</div>';
return $output;
}
```

Comment: Clarify `expanded` and `minimized`.